# Cannot read big int from ifstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a txt file:

```
4286484840 4286419048 4286352998
```

(They are RGB values.)

I would like to store them in a vector.

```
void read_input(const char* file, std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::ifstream f(file);
    if (!f)
    {
        std::cerr << file << "Read error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int c;
    while (f >> c)
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        input.push_back(c);
    }

    std::cout << "Vector size is: " << input.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
Vector size is: 0
```

However with the following file:

```
1 2 3
```

The result is:

```
1
2
3
Vector size is: 3
```

What is wrong with the first file? Are the numbers too big?

Comment: `int c;` -> `unsigned long c;` and `std::vector<int>` -> `std::vector<unsigned long>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the numbers are likely too big.  On the most common systems nowadays, `int` is 32 bits, and its max value is `2^31-1`, although it's only guaranteed to be `2^15-1` (requiring 16 bits).  You can check your limits with:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
}
```

In order to guarantee representation for values that large, you can use `long long`.  `unsigned long` will do too, but barely.  If you need integers of a specific size, I recommend you take a look at the [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header.

Answer (score 0):

```
void read_input(const char* file, std::vector<unsigned long int>& input)
{

    std::ifstream f(file);
    if (!f)
    {
        std::cerr << file << "Read error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int c;
    while (f >> c)
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        input.push_back(c);
    }

    std::cout << "Vector size is: " << input.size() << std::endl;
}
```